# Error on executing Global temp tables in SSIS package on server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, global-temp-tables

I have an SSIS package which is as below.
The **DelayValidation Property** of data flow task is **True**
The **DelayValidation Property** of all Execute SQL task is **True**
The **RetainSameConnection Property** of Source connection task is **True**
 The Package runs fine on **my local machine** but when it is deployed on **Server**, it gives the **error**.
*How can this be fixed? Please help.*
[image: SSIS Package]

[image: Data flow task]

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Any reason you're using a global temp table? Why not just a permanent table, it saves a lot of hassle

Comment: A temporary table (even a "global" one) only lasts as long as the connection/scope that created it. You *can't* reference your temporary table on your latter Execute T-SQL task as it no longer exists; it has been implicitly `DROP`ed.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have to use the Global temp table because i don't have access to create Permanent table on Source DB.